# How to use Vim to edit files using SCP but across different Subnets?

Tags: networking, vim, ssh, scp

I'm learning about Networks and recently found out that the SCP protocol is used to edit files on some other computer. Now the thing is that the other computer should be on the same network. So I was curious about how to edit files across different networks?

Additional information: In my college we have computer labs. Each lab has exactly one switch. All the computers in a particular lab are connected to the switch. Also all of the labs have Internet connection. So if I want to edit a file using VIM on a computer that my friend is on but he is on a different lab, then how can I do it?

Comment: Whether you can do that or not depends on your network's configuration, not on Vim.  If you can `scp` from one machine to another, Vim will be able to edit files on the remote machine as well.  If you can't `scp`, Vim won't work either.

Comment: Do you have an account on your friend's machine?  Is it running an ssh / scp server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Application-level protocols like SSH and HTTP use an underlying TCP/IP connection; they work regardless of the subnet (barring extended networking features like firewalls, packet filters, network proxies, etc.)

So, if your friend's computer is reachable via the Internet, or just the local lab network, and you have the IP address / DNS name of his computer, and the corresponding port (22 for SSH / SCP) is not blocked, and you have a login on his computer, you can remotely edit files there.

If your end goal is remote editing, I would approach this via these steps, each building on top of the previous one:

1. `ping othercomputer`
2. `ssh user@othercomputer`
3. In Vim: `:edit scp://user@othercomputer/path/to/file`